# Changing the contents of an array in a recursive function

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, backtracking

I am having trouble understanding something regarding recursion and arrays.

basically, what the program does is to check what is the maximum weights of items that can be placed in two boxes. I know it's far from perfect as it is right now, but this is not the point.

Generally everything is working properly, however, now I decided that I want to see the contents of each box when the weight is maximal. For this purpose I tried using arr1 and arr2.

I don't understand why I get different results for arr1 and arr2 (the first options gives me what I want, the second does not).

This is the program:

```
#define N 5
int help(int items[N][2], int box1[N], int box2[N], int rules[N][N], 
         int optimal,int current_weight,int item,int arr1[],int arr2[])
{
  if (item == N)
    {
      if(current_weight>optimal) //This is the first option
        {
          memcpy(arr1,box1,sizeof(int)*N);
          memcpy(arr2,box2,sizeof(int)*N);
        }
      return current_weight;
    }
  int k = items[item][1]; int sol;
  for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; i+j <= k; j++)
        {
          box1[item] += i; box2[item] += j;
          if (islegal(items, box1, box2, rules))
            {
              sol = help(items, box1, box2, rules, optimal, 
                   current_weight + (i + j)*items[item][0],item+1,arr1,arr2);
              if (sol > optimal)
                {
                  optimal = sol;
                  memcpy(arr1,box1,sizeof(int)*N); //This is the second option
                  memcpy(arr2,box2,sizeof(int)*N);
                }
            }
          box1[item] -= i; box2[item] -= j;
        }
    }
  return optimal;
}

int insert(int items[N][2], int rules[N][N])
{
  int box1[N] = { 0 }; int arr1[N] = { 0 };
  int box2[N] = { 0 }; int arr2[N] = { 0 };
  int optimal = 0;
  int x = help(items, box1, box2, rules,0, 0,0,arr1,arr2);
  print(arr1, N);
  print(arr2, N);
  return x;
}
```

Can anyone explain what causes the difference? Why the first option is correct and the second is not? I couldn't figure it out by my own.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because when you pass `box1` and `box2` to help, they are mutated by `help`. It's pretty obvious from the algorithm that you want them to not be mutated. So, we can do as follows:

```
int help(int items[N][2], int box1in[N], int box2in[N], int rules[N][N], 
         int optimal,int current_weight,int item,int arr1[],int arr2[])
{
    int box1[N];
    int box2[N];
    memcpy(box1, box1in, sizeof(int)*N);
    memcpy(box2, box2in, sizeof(int)*N);
```

Your algorithm may still have problems but that problem is now removed.